# where the half of the storage is filled in unity build?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-engine

this is the build report of game for Windows X86 total user asset size is 28.9 MB including dll's even though full build size is 62.1 MB more than twice the asset size where all the storage is gone?

---

```
Build Report
Uncompressed usage by category (Percentages based on user generated assets only):
Textures               8.1 mb    27.9% 
Meshes                 0.0 kb    0.0% 
Animations             17.8 kb   0.1% 
Sounds                 385.1 kb  1.3% 
Shaders                151.3 kb  0.5% 
Other Assets           728.8 kb  2.5% 
Levels                 4.4 mb    15.1% 
Scripts                1.9 mb    6.6% 
Included DLLs          13.3 mb   46.0% 
File headers           44.6 kb   0.2% 
Total User Assets      28.9 mb   100.0% 
Complete build size    62.1 mb
Used Assets and files from the Resources folder, sorted by uncompressed size:
 1.0 mb  1.7% Assets/TextMesh Pro/Resources/Fonts & Materials/LiberationSans SDF.asset
 510.4 kb    0.8% Assets/Sprites/Object/level 5/DoorUnlocked.png
 507.2 kb    0.8% Assets/Sprites/Object/level 5/Saw.png
 403.5 kb    0.6% Assets/Sprites/Object/level 4/Igloo.png
 385.1 kb    0.6% Assets/Audio/379323__13fpanska-marval-lukas__run.wav
 344.4 kb    0.5% Assets/TextMesh Pro/Fonts/LiberationSans.ttf
 341.5 kb    0.5% Assets/TextMesh Pro/Sprites/EmojiOne.png
 333.5 kb    0.5% Assets/Sprites/Object/level 1/Tree_2.png
 320.8 kb    0.5% Assets/Sprites/Object/level 3/Tree 1.png
 304.8 kb    0.5% Assets/Sprites/Object/level 1/Tree_3.png
 270.2 kb    0.4% Assets/Sprites/Object/level 2/Tree.png
 259.7 kb    0.4% Assets/TextMesh Pro/Resources/Fonts & Materials/LiberationSans SDF - Fallback.asset
 166.0 kb    0.3% Assets/Sprites/Object/level 5/Barrel (2).png
 166.0 kb    0.3% Assets/Sprites/Object/level 5/Barrel (1).png
```

Comment: megabits or megabytes?

Comment: I'm guessing it's the actual Unity engine; try turning engine stripping on

Comment: @mjwills megabytes

Answer (score 0):

Check the build folder and have a look at which files are taking up the most space.
You can then work out where the xtra space is going that is not counted in the build report, ie,

I think in your case the .exe is taking some space (2-3 megs)
I believe GI data is not counted towards the total (gamename_Data\GI) - Could be 0 - 100+ megs)
Also add in MonoBleedingEdge Runtimes (6.5 megs)
gamename_Data\StreamingAssets - Isn't counted at all.

etc.

Comment: 37.3 MB by CaptainCoolData(folder)-------------4.96MB by MonoBledingEdge(folder)---------------625KB by game exe--------901KB by unityCrashaHandler32 exe------------------------------------19MB by UnityPlayer.dll  , what is UnityPlayer.dll?

Comment: Unity split the functionality from the .exe into two parts. So it's basically the Unity engine as a .dll. I believe this occurred from 2017 onwards.

Comment: If this answers your question, please mark it as correct :)